reinforcement learning reward choices
To start with, this is not a homework thing. In my attempt to finally get a practical working knowledge of table based re-inforcement learning, I came up with a very silly and easy dice game, serving as an example. But early on, I ran into problems, you people could help with.
The game

1 6 sided dice.
2 actions: roll another time or stop.
if your next roll is >= your previous roll, your score adds up. Else you are busted and get 0 score.
If you stop or busted, it is the next players turn.
The winner is, who has a total score of 20 first.

Example of a players turn: rolls 1, action: roll, rolls 3, action: stop => Has earned 4 points (3+1) which is added to the players total score.
The Q-table
From the above game description I concluded that the table has 6 states/rows, one for each dice roll. And 2 actions (roll again or stop).
First question: Is that really correct? After all, if you have rolled 15 times a 1 already (a turn-score of 15), is the same strategy optimal, compared to you having just rolled a 1 once? Does your accrued round-score impact the strategy?
Second question: Which score-number would you use to do the updating of the q-table after a turn? The accrued round-score or just the value of an individual roll of the last dice? Should there not be a difference between a player just picking stop before rolling and a player rolling but busting? How would that be implemented within that RL algorithm-framework?
What did I do before posting this question?
In search for answers, before asking here, I did:

Read the wikipedia article
searched and found and skimmed over tons of blogs and articles (most of which explain nothing, but just use some python library)
watched some youtube CS class about reinforcement learning, but their hand picked examples never seem to match with whatever problem I try to solve.

So, a concise answer might not be only useful for me, but for anyone who really wants to be able to use that (class of) algorithms successfully.

Try https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

@ray Oh - another stackexchange site I did not know existed!

I’m voting to close this question because others stated, that this question is better hosted at datascience.stackexchange.com, which is true.

Downside of that other site is that no one seems to be active there....

oops didn't read that you were planning to close this, I answered this one here.

@SachinHosmani I did not get any help on the datascience site. Just a community comment that they did not like my question.... So thank you for your effort.

Ideally, I would include all of the following in the state

player's last roll
player's accrued score
opponent's accrued score

But that makes the state space 6x20x20 large. If that is unviable, another option could be to define the state as

the player's last roll
the difference between the player's accrued score and the opponent's accrued score, normalized by the max score (which is 20 here) and discretized

To give an example for the second parameter, imagine you just rolled a 2 and you're now at 19 and the opponent is at 3. So the normalized difference is (19 - 3) / 20 = 0.8. If we bucketize this normalized difference into 10 buckets to discretize it, 0.8 would get the bucket 8. All this is like saying "the opponent is 80% of the way behind, so they are unlikely to catch up, so you can just stop your current turn and wait for your next turn".
And when the opponent is playing and they see that they are 80% of the way behind, they are quite likely to lose if they don't take enough risk, so they would learn to not give up their turn easily.

First question: Is that really correct? After all, if you have rolled 15 times a 1 already (a turn-score of 15), is the same strategy optimal, compared to you having just rolled a 1 once? Does your accrued round-score impact the strategy?

I can't think of how the accrued round-score would impact the strategy. It is an MDP. How you got there is irrelevant. Where you are is relevant. So, the total accrued score would be relevant, as I described earlier.

Second question: Which score-number would you use to do the updating of the q-table after a turn? The accrued round-score or just the value of an individual roll of the last dice? Should there not be a difference between a player just picking stop before rolling and a player rolling but busting? How would that be implemented within that RL algorithm-framework?

Assuming you're planning to use Q-learning here

(image from the free book Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction by Sutton and Barto)
so what reward r do we use use to update the Q-table there when take an action? There is no fixed right or wrong answer here. We'd need to experiment and find a) what works best b) what converges fast enough. Here are some options to consider

0 reward for everything except winning (winning means crossing 20 points), huge reward for winning
to speed things up a little, we could give an intermediate reward as the number of points you get from rolling the die (if you lose all points, you get negative of accrued score as reward)


I currently did implement the 6x2 approach and it just did the obvious. So I considered to use (21 21 6) or (21 21 21 6) which yields a q-table-size of 2646 or 55566 respectively. An already high turn-score is at risk if you roll low. So, stopping a turn when the result is "good" already, while you do not risk losing the match makes sense. The bucketizing sounds interesting. But I think I will go with the (21 21 21 6) version next, if any, to have a reference for later, more refined versions.
